# Nest JS - About passing parameters to Decorators

Tags: typescript, caching, nestjs, decorator, interceptor

I'm working on the cache mechanism.
I need a dynamic cache key. (Module - Method Name - Some Request Parameters)
**Like this:**  usersModule_getUserById_5

```js
@CacheKey('userModule_getUserById' +request.body.id)
```

**Is it possible pass parameters this decorator ?**

I will use clear cache with module name or method name or user id on user data changes.

I have specified exactly where I want the sample code below.

```js
import {
  CacheInterceptor,
  CacheKey,
  CacheTTL,
  Controller,
  Get,
  Req,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
  @CacheTTL(3600)
  @CacheKey('userModule_getUserById.....') // ----> I need a dynamic request parameters on this decorator.
  @Get()
  async getHello(@Req() req: Request): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Hello World!');
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you wrap it in your own custom decorator. You should be able to get request parameters from the ctx there... see examples in docs

Comment: You may be right i will try this, just what i wanted to know is is it possible to pass parameters to decorators

Comment: Good luck! It should be pretty straight forward following the docs